# Java jdbc mysql error

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm working on a program for fun but the `MySQL` driver and connection code isn't working properly I got the error

```
Error: no suitable driver found
```

MeanWhile my code contains the `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` line. I have the newest `MySQL` jar file in my class path. any suggestions I could try to fix the problem

```
private void connect() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,user,pass);
        stmt = con.createStatement();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        error = true;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the .newInstance() when it did not workcorrectly after a few tries and edits.

Comment: Can you please recheck the mysql library added properly in the classpath

Comment: http://central.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.6/mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar

Comment: If you use a recent version of the MySQL JDBC driver, you don't even need anymore to load the class first Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"). Starting from JDBC 4.0

Comment: It is, no errors in the project or called to methods, I've tried the jar you linked as well still the same error

Comment: please provide the exact error and the value of URL

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql//198.50.***.**
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)

Comment: i replaced the last 5 digits of the ip with * for my own pretection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is in the syntax of the `URL` which is not correct you forgot the colon after `mysql`, it should be `jdbc:mysql://...` for more details about the syntax of the `URL` in case of `mysql` please refer to this [web page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html)

Comment: where have you seen that variable `URL` is initialized ?